# mysqli insert Is not working when uploading large file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this weird problem never faced it before. the code is working fine when i upload a small file but when i upload larg file (105mb) the query dose not work and gives me this output

> MySQL server has gone away - 2006 ../uploads/sermons/2019.03.08-Bro-GK.mp3

```
$uploadDirectory = "../uploads/sermons/";
require '../includes/config.php'; // this contains the connection ($conn)
$errors = []; // Store all foreseen and unforseen errors here

$fileExtensions = ['mp3','wav']; // Get all the file extensions

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileTmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileExtension = explode('.',$fileName);
$fileExtension = end($fileExtension);
$fileExtension = strtolower($fileExtension);

$uploadPath = $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName);


    if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions)) {
        $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a mp3 or wav file";
    }



    if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {

            $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["Title"]);
            $speaker = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["Speaker"]);
            $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["date"]);
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
            $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["Description"]);
            $query = "Insert into `sermons` (`Title`,`Description`,`Speaker`,`Date`,`Link`) values('$title','$description','$speaker','$date','$uploadPath');";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)." - ".mysqli_errno($conn)." ".$uploadPath);
```

Comment: "*when i upload larg file (105mb) the query dose not work*" Large file uploading is not related to MYSQL error. u need to increase `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: is that the only error that you a re getting?

Comment: @devpro - How is "MySQL server has gone away" not related to MySQL?

Comment: in this example, its happening due to large file size, error is related to MYSQL, but in this example, there is no need to fix anything related to query. in this example just need to check file size and its limit to post. and i have mentioned *Large file uploading* @PaulSpiegel

Comment: @devpro - But it probably also has nothing to do with `upload_max_filesize`, since the upload didn't fail. It seems to be, that the mysql session is timed out.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: i agreed, but OP mentioned error occur after uploading large size ... and working fine with small size.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: i think this is a good idea, if connection moves into this check `if ($didUpload) {` isnt it?

Comment: @devpro - That might work, if the DB connection is not mixed with other "config" stuff too much.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: yes u are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're running into a read timeout, because the upload takes longer than the script keeps the connection open. Try setting the value of the `MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT` to something suitable like so `mysqli_options($conn, MYSQLI_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, value_in_seconds);`. You'll probably have to setup `$conn` before actually connecting, in case you run into this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76703